# Jaca 8. Как сохранить сторонний метод в классе?

Tags: java, многопоточность, lambda, java-8

Я хочу реализовать класс, который будет управлять потоками в моей библиотеке.

Суть в том, что мне необходимо создавать методы в других классах, выполняющиеся параллельно.

Предположим я хочу реализовать метод, который в несколько потоков обрабатывает список и возвращает map.

Для этого в методе я собираюсь создать объект класса `threads_manager` и передать в него функцию обработки данных и дополнительную информацию (кол-во потоков и прочее).

Далее в конструкторе создать `n` объектов класса, на следующего `Thread` и потом запустить их.

**Вопрос:** правильно ли я рассуждаю и как можно передать в конструктор метод что бы потом передать его в еще один конструктор?

Заранее извиняюсь, в java я новичок и C++ еще плотно сидит у меня в голове.

Comment: В java методы никуда не передаются. Нужно сделать объект с нужными методами и передавать его. И в точке назначения обращайтесь к методам этого объекта.

В Java 8 задача немного упрощается, если в качестве "метода-параметра" будет использован функциональный интерфейс. Тогда в качестве объекта можно передать  лямбду, что немного сократит количество набираемых строк кода.

Comment: Про дямбды можно почитать здесь например https://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/ Даже есть такие понятия как ссылки на методы и конструкторы (но это лишь syntax sugar)

Comment: @Sergey но я хочу сделать так, что бы при помощи моего менеджера можно было бы распараллелить любую функцию. С одинаковым окл-вом параметров хотя бы. Таких паттернов в Java нет?

Comment: Всё можно распараллелить

Comment: @Sergey да, но как это сделать при помощи единственного класса?

Comment: Не знаю. Ваша формулировка задачи очень расплывчата. Почитайте про шаблоны проектировния. В частности про стратегию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передать метод напрямую нельзя, можно передать ***Функциональный интерфейс***(Интерфейс имеющий ровно один абстрактный метод), в самой джаве есть несколько вариантов: Function(Приминает один аргумент, возварщает значение), Consumer(Принимает один аргумент, ничего не возвращает), Producer(Не принимает ничего, возвращает значение). Также можно написать свой. Например один из моих:

```
public static interface CommandAction
    {
        public void performCommand(Message msg, String[] args, Guild giuld);
    }
```

После чего такой интерфейс можно передать разными способами:
***Анонимный класс:***

```
new CommandAction()
{
    public void perfromCommand(Message msg, String[] args, Guild guild)
    {
        //SomeCode
    }
}
```

***Лямда-выражение:***

```
(msg, args, guild) -> {
//SomeCode
}
```

***Ссылка на метод:***

```
public static void SomeMethod(Message msg, String[] args, Guild guild)
{
    //SomeCode
}
//В вызове
SomeClass::SomeMethod
```